# Compartilhamento no Instagram

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook-javascript-sdk

Eu estava dando uma linda na nova API do instagram https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/ e percebi que não contém alguns recursos que vejo por ai.

Alguém sabe me dizer como funciona esses sites de agendamentos? Gostaria de entender como são realizadas as publicações.